# comment package: Show/hide comments Inside a section title

Tags: comments

I'm pretty close to being a LaTeX beginner. I'm hoping to use the comment package to indicate author's names (i.e. who's responsible for writing) on each section of a shared paper. This could then temporarily be shown in the TOC.
But in the manual: "with the opening and closing commands again on a line of their own."
Clearly my code won't work and I'm not clear how to solve it. Any recommendations?
Much appreciated!
Michael

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{sectionauthor}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section \sectionauthor Me \endsectionauthor }
\section{Second Section \sectionauthor You \endsectionauthor }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only in the ToC and not in the main document?

Comment: Please bear with me, as this is my first submission. I guess I'd like to see it in the section names too!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it: the command `\sectionauthor` must have two different meanings and we accomplish it by changing its definition inside a group when we typeset the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd{\sectionauthor}[1]{%
  \unskip % remove the space before it
  \\ % go to a new line
  {\normalsize\normalfont #1}%
}
\newcommand{\titlesectionauthor}[1]{%
  {\normalfont (#1)}% section author in parentheses
}


\begin{document}

\begingroup % make the change to \sectionauthor local
\let\sectionauthor\titlesectionauthor
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\section{First Section \sectionauthor{Me}}
\section{Second Section \sectionauthor{You}}
\end{document}
```

I use `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox` because it's more practical than the standard `\DeclareRobustCommand`. It's necessary to declare `\sectionauthor` as robust, because this will make LaTeX write it unmodified in the `.toc` file, so we can use it also for giving it a new meaning.

I have applied some formatting instructions, modify them to suit your needs.

[image]

---

You can implement a “toggle on and off” on the two possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% comment the following line if you don't want the author to show in the body
\newtoggle{sectionauthor}
% comment the following line if you don't want the author to show in the TOC
\newtoggle{tocsectionauthor}

\toggletrue{sectionauthor}
\toggletrue{tocsectionauthor}

\newrobustcmd{\sectionauthor}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{sectionauthor}
    {% what to do if the toggle is true
     \unskip % remove the space before it
     \\ % go to a new line
     {\normalsize\normalfont #1}%
    }
    {% what to do if the toggle is false
     \unskip % remove the space before it
    }%
}

\newcommand{\tocsectionauthor}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{tocsectionauthor}
    {% what to do if the toggle is true
     {\normalfont (#1)}% section author in parentheses
    }
    {% what to do if the toggle is false
     \unskip % remove the space before it
    }%
}


\begin{document}

\begingroup % make the change to \sectionauthor local
\let\sectionauthor\tocsectionauthor
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\section{First Section \sectionauthor{Me}}
\section{Second Section \sectionauthor{You}}
\end{document}
```

The output without commenting (a `%` in front of the line suffices) the two lines is the same as above. If we comment only the first line, we get

[image]

If we comment only the second line we remove the names from the TOC, but leave them in the body. Commenting out both lines the names disappear completely.

Comment: Much appreciated! I should have been more explicit. I was using the comment package to have the choice of include or exclude. My inexperience is preventing me from seeing how to implement that in your code.

Comment: @mfolkes I've added the necessary code.

Comment: Wow. Impressive and appreciated! thanks very much.